# Turn off workspace switch-over display

Tags: lubuntu, lightdm, workspace-switcher, wmctrl, lxdm

Using LightDM and `wmctrl` to set up workspaces and switch between them. How can I deactivate the screen which is very briefly shown when switching between workspaces?

Answer (score 0):

When I use `wmctrl -s <workspace#>`, my screen switches workspaces and shows this: [openbox workspace swithcing notification (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeoFB.jpg)

If this is the thing you want to deactivate, open `Openbox Configuration Manager` from `Menu > Preferences > Openbox Configuration Manager` or by running `obconf`, go to the `Desktops` tab, and deselect `Show a notification when switching desktops`.